Problem Filter with extract Button Power BI DAX
I have a problem with extraction Button in Power BI.
When I apply this Formula, my table on PBI give me a result for each company (X,Y,Z) whereas I just want the result for the company selected with my button (company x for example).
I used this formula :
conditionCompany =
VAR dateDebut =
    TODAY () - 3600
VAR distinctcountemployee =
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'ODBC - personnalInfo + Address'[employee] ) )
VAR NbAddress =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'ODBC - personnalInfo + Address'[Full address] ),
        FILTER (
            'ODBC - personnalInfo + Address',
            'ODBC - personnalInfo + Address'[dateStart_SA] >= dateDebut
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( NbAddress / distinctcountemployee <> 1, "Changement d'adresse", "RAS" )

Someone has an idea ?
Thanks for your help
I would like to get my result for one company

You may need to add  a filter condition based on the company (I assumed this is the needed column) to your CALCULATE :
 conditionCompany =
    VAR dateDebut = TODAY() - 3600
    VAR selectedCompany = SELECTEDVALUE('ODBC - personnalInfo + Address'[company])
    VAR distinctcountemployee =
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('ODBC - personnalInfo + Address'[employee]),
            'ODBC - personnalInfo + Address'[company] = selectedCompany
        )
    VAR NbAddress =
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('ODBC - personnalInfo + Address'[Full address]),
            FILTER(
                'ODBC - personnalInfo + Address',
                'ODBC - personnalInfo + Address'[dateStart_SA] >= dateDebut &&
                'ODBC - personnalInfo + Address'[company] = selectedCompany
            )
        )
    RETURN
        IF(NbAddress / distinctcountemployee <> 1, "Changement d'adresse", "RAS")

